# i want customize header and footer through wp-admin panel

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want customize front site header and footer from admin panel anyone can suggest me and what plugin that provide header and footer customize easily from admin panel please suggest me how I can do

Answer (score 0):

There is no special plugin. There are 2 ways:

1. You can choose the theme which allows to customize header and footer from admin panel
2. You simply open files header.php and footer.php from your theme folder and customize them manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this from Wordpress admin panel Appearance-> Customize option.

But i would suggest that you can manage it properly from the your selected themes style.css file as per your requirement.

Comment: I am not sure but there is a Divi Builder plugin, that will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Divi Builder plugin - This is a page builder plugin. This will not give options for managing header and footer

Comment: thanks for suggestion but i want customize header from  Appearance-> Customize and customize  all header div like menu logo and background-color and change all contents color  if any plugin for this

Answer (score 0):

```html
 function theme_prefix_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );
 }
 add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_prefix_setup' );
```

This code in your functions.php can add the options for uploading logo in the customize options.

To make footer manageable from admin side you can register a sidebar and call it in footer. You can style that as per your design.